# SQL Server 2008 db shrink error

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard edition with 3 tb data. My disc is full. I want to shrink the `.mdf` file. I've deleted many rows from my db. And I launch

```
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(my_db, TRUNCATEONLY)
```

I got error

> Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
>   A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded.

I tried to do it in single user mode result is same. We have increased disk size to 4.5 tb and retried shrinking, result is same.

`dbcc checkdb` command shows no error on db.

Does anyone know what is problem?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying both the file name and the target size in MB, e.g.

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE('filename', 20);
```

Or the TRUNCATEONLY option, which doesn't try any of the nasty stuff like reorganizing all of your physical data:

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE('filename', TRUNCATEONLY);
```

Also you could try making sure the database is in single user mode first:

```
ALTER DATABASE db SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

...and turn off any backup / log backup or other maintenance jobs that may be conflicting with your shrink operation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I've tried with specifying file size. And I do not perorm any backup or any other job. And I also tried single user mode. But unsuccessfull :(

Comment: Have you tried using `DBCC SHRINKFILE` instead of `DBCC SHRINKDATABASE`?

Comment: I've tried 3 variants. DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(db,70); DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(sgsn,truncateonly);DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(sgsn,70,truncateonly); no reuslts

Comment: yes I've tried `dbcc shrinkfile` instead of shrinkdatabase, result is same